# Erro em Webservices Json C# "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0."

Tags: c#, json, web-service

Ola, estou recebendo um erro na execução do meu código, em outra aplicação o mesmo código funciona, já mudei os `using`, mas não funciona.

```
public String CriaPeca(String token, String ip, String autor, bool seguranca, Dictionary<String, String> metadadosDoc, String nomeArquivo)
{
    // Variáveis para retorno do webservice e do método
    //var WSResult = "";
    var id = "";

    // Configuração dos parametros de entrada
    var URL_Base = "";

    // Caso exista necessidade de segurança deve ser usado HTTPS
    if (seguranca)
        URL_Base = "https://";
    else URL_Base = "http://";

    URL_Base = URL_Base + ip + "/docflow/";

    var URL_Servico = "ws/peca/cadastro?auth=" + token;

    // Criando metadados gerais para o documento
    var metadados = "login_autor=" + autor;

    // Montando metadados especificos do documento
    var metTemp = metadadosDoc;
    // Concatenando metadados gerais com especificos
    metadados = metadados + "&" + metTemp;

    try
    {
        var client = new RestClient(URL_Base);
        // Neste ploco fazemos o cadastro da Peça
        var request = new RestRequest(URL_Servico, Method.POST);


        request.AddQueryParameter("response_type", "json");
        request.AddParameter("user_login", "admin");
        request.AddFile("bin_peca", nomeArquivo);
        request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        foreach (String campo in metadadosDoc.Keys)
        {
            String metadadoslimpo = removerAcentos(metadadosDoc[campo]);
            request.AddParameter(campo, metadadoslimpo);
        }

        var response = client.Execute(request);


        Console.Out.WriteLine(response.Content);


            //Erro // Erro // Erro
        JObject ResultJObject = JObject.Parse(response.Content);

        var status = ResultJObject["message"]["type"].Value<string>();
        if (status.Equals("error"))
        {
            status = ResultJObject["message"]["value"].Value<string>();
        }
        id = status;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        id = Convert.ToString(ex);
        Console.WriteLine("--> Nao foi possivel criar o documento via WebService <--\nErro: " + ex.ToString());
    }

    return id;
}
```

A Mensagem de erro é essa.

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

O response.Content esta dessa forma

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, evite usar imagens quando a mensagem pode ser mostrada via texto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O WebService retornou uma página HTML especificando um erro. Perceba a tag `title` em `Response.Content`

> JBoss Web/7.0.10.Final - **Error Report**

O código tenta tratar o retorno como um JSON, mas ele é um HTML, esta é a causa do erro.

Comment: Estranho porque eu mando o AddQueryParameter para receber json, o webservices me da o retorno das duas formas, eu estou mandando errado ?

Comment: @RenanSilveira Não necessariamente. Aparentemente o servidor não está "dando bola" para o que você quer receber. Lembre-se que a resposta do servidor pode ser completamente diferente daquilo que você espera, ele não tem nenhuma "obrigação" de mandar os dados como você espera. Veja qual é a mensagem de erro que ele está te mandando, isso já deve te dar um norte.

Comment: Entendi, Obrigado